# fopen won't create a file, instead dies

Tags: php, die

I am trying to create a file in PHP and it won't work. I am using the `fopen` command to do so but it's not working.

I have a variable `$EmailAddress` that stores a users email address and when I try and say

```
$myfile = fopen("$EmailAddress.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to create file!");
```

I've even tried using the name instead of the emaill address and it still won't work.

```
$myfile = fopen($_POST['name'] . ".txt", "w+") or die(......);
```

Which according to what I am seeing SHOULD completely work, but for some reason every single time I run this code I get the `die` message. Any idea why?

Comment: `)` missing before `;`

Comment: That was a typo I made typing it on here. In my actual code, I have the `)`.

Comment: Well, is error reporting enabled? You should get an `E_WARNING` if `fopen` cannot open the file.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Uh, no?

Comment: @GenericUser01 have you checked the permissions to create file?

Comment: could you show us what's inside the variable? Have you tried to create a file with a static name?

Comment: The webserver probably does not have permission to write in the directory you're trying to create the file in. Also, since you're using an emailadress for the filename, your attempt to create a file might contain invalid characters?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino The emaill address that the user types in is in the variable. I put a statement in to print out the value to make sure it is storing it correctly.

Comment: @Glubus I switched it to just the name, so it didn't have the @ and it still wont work.

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script to get a meaningful error message.